# make search engine on codeigniter for several tables using join and or_like

Tags: codeigniter, search

//model

```
function search($keyword){
    $this->db->select('*')->from('rf_barang');
    $this->db->join('brand', 'rf_barang.KODE_BRAND = brand.KODE_BRAND');
    $this->db->join('jenis', 'rf_barang.KODE_JENIS = jenis.KODE_jenis');
    $this->db->join('tipe', 'rf_barang.KODE_TIPE = tipe.KODE_tipe');
    $this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.KODE_KATEGORI = kategori.KODE_kategori');
    $this->db->join('rf_gambar', 'rf_gambar.KODE_BARANG = rf_barang.KODE_barang');
    $this->db->or_like('rf_barang.KODE_BARANG', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('MODEL', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('NAMA_BRAND', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('NAMA_JENIS', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('NAMA_TIPE', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('NAMA_KATEGORI', $keyword);
    $this->db->group_by('rf_barang.KODE_BARANG');  
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

from my query, it shows data that i don't need .. How to show just data that i want it ?

Comment: what data you need and what not? explain that in detail. If you are taking about specific fields from each table instead of all (*) fields, you can update your ``select`` statement and write all required columns in that.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->select('*')` is the method that is selecting the fields that are returned by the query. To specify fields, you can list them individually here instead of `'*'`, which includes every field from every table in the query.

If you want to only include the values`rf_barang.KODE_BRAND` and `kategori.KODE_KATEGORI` for example, you would write: `$this->db->select('rf_barang.KODE_BRAND, kategori.KODE_KATEGORI')`.

You can also include only all of the values from one of the tables like this: `$this->db->select('kategori.*')`.

Here's a reference to the MySQL SELECT statement:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html